# What are the options available to encrypt a SQL Server Express database?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-express

We have a team of sales persons who travel often carrying a laptop loaded with Sales data in a SQL Server Express database. What are the options available to encrypt a SQL Server Express database?

Comment: travelling salesman problem? ;-)

Comment: Why not encrypt the entire laptop HDD?

Comment: Why would you want to encrypt the full database? I am just thinking that it may be a performance overhead. I have seen passwords encrypted before but never the full database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's your threat model? Are you trying to stop a casual thief who's stolen a laptop, or a determined hacker? Are you trying to protect just the data, or also the schema?

If you're using SQL Server Express 2005 or higher, then [it supports native asymmetric encryption](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3483931/SQL-Server-2005-Security---Part-3-Encryption.htm). But if you're trying to stop a determined hacker, then I think the best option would be to encrypt the whole disk using something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), or [BitLocker](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/bitlocker.aspx) for Vista/Windows7.

Comment: Trying to protect just the data, which may include confidential sales information of a Company. We are using SQL Server Express 2008 and the OS is Windows XP, so BitLocker wont help us. I'm exploring native asymmetric encryption on SQL Express.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using transparent encryption solution for SQL Server called [DbDefence](http://www.dbdefence.com/).
It is free for databases less than 77MB

Comment: less than 77 mb is crucial issue

Answer (score 0):

I see that others have mentioned a third party product.  If you are open to that, you can also consider [Encryptionizer for SQL Server](https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-server-encryption/), which supports all versions and editions of SQL Server from Express to Enterprise. Disclaimer: I am with NetLib Security.