# Stop exporting a SQL Server database to secure it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a vb.net windows form application with a database on SQL Server 2008 on the `./SQLEXPRESS` instance.

I have created a setup of my project using the link below..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/49b92ztk(v=vs.80).aspx

When a user installs my application, the database will be available for him, and user can just export the SQL Server database.

How can I secure my database so that user shouldn't have a easily available copy of my database?

I thought of creating a new password protected server (as I have created the database in above walkthrough)... while installation of my application on user's pc, other than `./sqlexpress`. And a complete copy of database used by my application will not be simply available for user to just export and get a copy of my database.

So could anyone please guide me...

Comment: If you send out your database to the client's computer, there's really nothing much you can do to prevent that user from copying or looking at it. If you cannot trust your own users with your database, then lock it away in a data center, and provide nothing but a service interface to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714640/what-are-the-options-available-to-encrypt-a-sql-server-express-database

Comment: thanks for your response.

Then how should i develop my desktop application, so that my database remains secured. I have developed an offline windows form based vb.net English-English Dictionary with its words and meanings in a database on sql server. But i don't want that users easily get a copy of the word database. 
Will you please be kind enough to post any link or tutorial from where i could learn, how to create a project with its database secured, and there is a performance issue too. Because its a large database of about 85 MB, having rows upto 2,03,147 ...
Thanks for any response...

Comment: The tutorial may be in java or vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is; how far do you want to go to protect your data?

Better protection of your data usually comes at the cost of more development time and likely less user friendliness, for example due to lower performance (encryption is not free). More complex code usually results in more support requests too.

Where the best balance is depends on your business model (if any) and on your user requirements.

Keep in mind that anything you deploy to an end-users machine is in the end vulnerable. If something is valuable enough there will be people trying to steal it.

So, you could argue that the best protection is not to deploy the data at all. You could back your end-user application with a web service and keep the data on your own server, for example in the cloud.

I've found however that you sometimes just need to trust your users. If you build a good product that makes them happy, they have no reason to steal from you. In fact, they are probably glad to pay you.

If you decide that you need to deploy the data and that you need to encrypt it, you should think about why you chose SQL Server. 
What database features do you need exactly? Do you need a fullblown database server for that?
Any local admin can gain control over any SQL Server database in seconds so the built-in SQL server authentication will not bring you a lot of benefits.

You could switch to SQLServer CE and keep the database within your application. That would make the database a lot harder to access for a regular user.

If all you're doing is looking up words, you may be better off with a different storage engine like Lucene.

Lucene is actually a search engine, so it's highly optimized for matching words or parts of words.

You can run Lucene inside your .NET application so you don't even need the end-user to install SQL Server. There is a .NET version of Lucene [here](http://lucenenet.apache.org/).

Lucene however doesn't protect your data. There's [tooling available](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) that will allow anybody to view and extract the data from the stored index files.

Since Lucene is open source though, you could extend it to support encrypted data storage (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2337643/64096)).

Comment: thanks **Marnix van Valen** for sharing this valuable information... 
This will help me a lot to understand the concept.

thanks again. :-)